# Show that $Q_n$ is a countable set

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $Q_n$ be the set of all [polygonal functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Piecewise_linear_function) that have nodes at $x=k/n$ for $k = 0, \dots, n$ and take on only rational values at these points. Check that $Q_n$ is a countable set, and hence that the union of the $Q_n$'s is a countable dense set in $C[0, 1]$.

I have no idea how to tackle this question.

Comment: what are polygonal functions?

Comment: It is a function that is linear on the intervals $[k/n, (k+1)/n]$, and $f(k/n)=g(k/n). Where $g \in Q_n$ and $f$ is a polynomial.

Comment: Hint: Each $f\in Q_n$ is uniquely determined by the tuple $(f(0),f(1/n),\ldots,f(1))\in\mathbb{Q}^n$, and $\mathbb{Q}^n$ is countable.

Comment: Dose (and take on only rational values at these points) mean that $f(k/n) \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: Yes. that's exactly what it means.

Comment: I solved it, thank you.